# Adding Delete functionality to my Edit controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to figure out how to have an edit function and a delete function from the same page in my application. At the moment my controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(CodeTagViewModel codeTagViewModel, FormCollection collection)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            List<Tag> tagsToAdd = new List<Tag>();

            codeTagViewModel.Tags = db.Tags.ToList();
            foreach (Tag tag in codeTagViewModel.Tags)
            {
                if (collection[tag.TagID.ToString()].ToString().Contains("true"))
                {
                    tagsToAdd.Add(tag);
                }
            }

            codeTagViewModel.SelectedTags = tagsToAdd;

            Code code = db.Code.Find(codeTagViewModel.CodeID);
            MapModelToCode(codeTagViewModel, code);

            db.Entry(code).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(codeTagViewModel);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult Edit(CodeTagViewModel codeTagViewModel, FormCollection collection)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            List<Tag> tagsToAdd = new List<Tag>();

            codeTagViewModel.Tags = db.Tags.ToList();
            foreach (Tag tag in codeTagViewModel.Tags)
            {
                if (collection[tag.TagID.ToString()].ToString().Contains("true"))
                {
                    tagsToAdd.Add(tag);
                }
            }

            codeTagViewModel.SelectedTags = tagsToAdd;

            Code code = db.Code.Find(codeTagViewModel.CodeID);
            MapModelToCode(codeTagViewModel, code);

            db.Code.Remove(code);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(codeTagViewModel);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And I've got the two buttons in my Edit view:

```
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </p>
```

And my view model looks like this:

```
public class CodeTagViewModel
{
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> SelectedTags { get; set; }        

    public int CodeID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string CMS { get; set; }
    public int DotNetVersion { get; set; }
    public string Dependencies { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string CodeFile { get; set; }
    public string TFSLocation { get; set; }

}
```

At the moment the delete button is doing nothing, it's not hitting the code at all.

I'm new to MVC and trying to figure out how it handles all of the background stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've also looked into the routing aspect and put in:

```
    //
    // POST: /Code/Edit/5
```

Above the delete function (it's the same as the one for the edit) and still nothing.

Comment: Does Save work as it should?

Comment: Save works, Edit works, but the problem is that the Delete part of Edit is not being hit

Comment: Can you post your save method as well for comparison

Comment: Also, if the page refreshes can you try setting a breakpoint on this line in the delete method `return RedirectToAction("Index");` and see if that one gets hit. It might be your if statement that doesn't come true.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't get hit, that's where I originally put the breakpoint. The edit is up there and works, I thought that would be a better comparison as it is the actual page I'm working on.

Comment: The reason I want to see Save is that you call the Edit method Edit and that one works. Do you call the Save method Edit too and it still works or is it called Save?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Save. Create? Or save the Edit? Because the Edit saves whatever changes were made on the form in the Edit view.

Comment: I'm refering to that your button has value="Save" and I want to know what code is hit when that button is pushed.

Comment: Does the Delete button hit the Edit method or just nothing at all?

Comment: Hits nothing whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because both the `Edit` and `Delete` button both do the same thing, they simply post the form. So they will **always post to the same place**.

You should change your delete button to be an `ActionLink`, then change your `Delete` method to be a `HttpGet`, pass in the ID of the item you want to delete and then retrieve and delete it.

Like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Code", new { CodeID = Model.CodeID })
```

Then in your action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete (int CodeID)
{
   //perform deletion
}
```

Otherwise, you'd have to use Javascript to automatically change the post URL of the form depending on which button was clicked, which is **nasty**.

Comment: I've tried using: @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "CodeController", "Delete", new { CodeID = Model.CodeID }) and I'm getting a 404

The resource cannot be found.

Comment: I also tried using: @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { CodeID = Model.CodeID })

And ended up with the error:
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Delete(Int32)' in 'StoRed.Controllers.CodeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Comment: @Kayra You have it slightly wrong. Take out the word `Controller`. Also `action` comes before controller, so you need `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Code", new { CodeID = Model.CodeID })`

Comment: @Kayra Make sure your parameter name in both your action link and your action method is **exactly** CodeID (casing is **important**).

Comment: @Kayra If they are the same, it might be conflicting with the default route, try changing both the action link parameter and the action method parameter to be called `id`, that will match the default route.

Comment: Made sure they were all exactly CodeID, then changed them to exactly id and still same error

Comment: Are you **sure** you changed them BOTH to JUST**id** (all lower case)? As looking at that error, it's complaining it can't find **id** (that's the default route).

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "CodeTagViewModel", new { id = Model.CodeID }, null)                            


        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                Code code = db.Code.Find(id);

                db.Code.Remove(code);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
                //return View(codeTagViewModel);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

Tried with and without the null, when I have the null it goes back to the 404 error

Comment: Shouldn't your controller be `Code` and not `CodeTagViewModel` in that link?

Comment: Ah my bad, I was trying different things and forgot to change it back. The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[StoRed.Models.Code]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[StoRed.Models.CodeTagViewModel]'.

Comment: That was why I was originally doing all that stuff with the view model, I can't seem to get around this without mapping everything

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

Both buttons submit the parent form, which is probably the same in your solution.

**Background Information:**

Your HTML Elements are inside a form element, if you submit through a button (doesn't matter which one). The browser will check the url that is given in the forms attribute.

**Solution:**

Put EDIT in a seperate form - with a reference to the edit url (with the entire model)
and then create a seperate form - with a reference to the delete url-  with the ModelID and the Delete button. (not with the entire model!)

Change your function of delete, so it only needs the ModelID as a parameter (instead of the whole model).

***Off you go :)***

Comment: Do you mean having something like this at the bottom of my view? 

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
     <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
}

Comment: Yes, but you need to add the key of your model also. Eg. <form method="post"><input type="hidden" id="ModelId" name="ModelId" /><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></form> and then don't forget to edit your method to require the modelId as only parameter, instead of the entire viewmodel :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you trid changing you method name to Delete?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(CodeTagViewModel codeTagViewModel, FormCollection collection)
    {...
```

I see no reason for namin the method Edit and setting ActionName to Delete.

Comment: Yeah I've tried this too, still doesn't hit the code. Just refreshes the page

Answer (score 0):

You have two Action methods with the same name and parameters. Doesn't it throw a compile error? Also in the view you have two submit buttons. which action is your form pointing to?

Point your form to the ActionMethod "Edit".

Add name attributes to your submit buttons

```
 <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name ="Edit"/>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="Remove"/>
</p>
```

Then in the controller action method:

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CodeTagViewModel codeTagViewModel, FormCollection collection)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       if((collection["Edit"]=="Save") && (collection["Remove"] == null)
        {
           // perform edit operation
        }
        else if((collection["Edit"]== null) && (collection["Remove"] == Delete)
        {
           // perform delete operation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does when they are both Edit, I've changed it to Delete it an attempt to get it to work but to no avail. As I said, I don't really know how MVC links them in the background so I don't know what to name it so that the view will find it

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [[HttpDelete]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpdeleteattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) attribute

Comment: It didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Know your basics... ^^

[HTTPDelete] is good for API's, but for .Net MVC you mostly need [HTTPPost] (submitting things) and [HTTPGet] -> getting things.